# Verification error on running blackberry application

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, java-me

I am working on a blackberry application that was developed by someone else. I tried creating and running other applications. All the applications work except this specific one.

For this application I need the secure element signatures. I got signature keys from blackberry and I requested the secure element signatures.

Whenever I run the application on a simulator it works perfectly. However when I try to run it on Blackberry Bold 9900, it tells me `'application name' has verification errors` and sometimes it says application terminated and other times it says `'net_rim_tsm_lib' not found.`. Currently it says `'net_rim_tsm_lib' not found`.

I am not sure what is wrong with it. Please help.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: I did not post this to be edited. Does anyone know an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the web and asking co-workers, I found out what was the problem. Basically, I was trying to use the secure element and the signing keys given to me by BlackBerry do not have permission to use the secure element. For my purpose, I do not need to access the secure element so I just took that part of the application out and it worked fine. However if you need to access the secure element, then you need to get the signing keys for the secure element. You can ask for them from BlackBerry, my request was not approved so I was not able to get the signing keys. Good luck with getting them.

Just a note, while searching over the web I found many reasons for the verification error. I am not sure if all of that is just BS and the whole reason behind the verification error is just some signing keys. So I am not sure if this is true for all of your issues.

Thanks